# php htmlspecialchars and jquery .text()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I ran into an issue recently. I have a system where users can post stuff. One of the fields is the **title** field. So to save user input safely I use htmlspecialchars on the user submitted title and send it to a function that then saves to the database (after using mysql_real_escape)

Now on the client's side I use json get to fetch this title

```
$.getJSON("PHPFILE", function(json) {
   // let's say json.title is the title we need so...
   var title = json.title;
}
```

Now the thing is this user given title value can contain anything, even html tags (for reference let's say it now contains

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;Some Text!
```

so since I use jquery I thought of clearing those using the .text() function

```
var cleanTitle = $(title).text();
alert(cleanTitle);
```

However this immediately throws an error. In chrome it says

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression ...
```

So I verified if this **title** variable is a string. And it is indeed a string. (Btw for some reason if this variable contains only numbers there is no error)

Using the following however gives me the text but the tags aren't removed

```
var cleanTitle = $.parseHTML(title);
cleanTitle = $(cleanTitle).text();
alert(cleanTitle);
```

This outputs

```
<script>alert('')</script>Some Text!
```

How can I remove all html tags? Any suggestions? I am planning to use this title text to set Browser title. Thanks.

Comment: Try this : `var cleanTitle = $('<div />').append( $('<div />').html( title ).text() ).text()`

Comment: Since you're using PHP, have you thought about using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). This would strip it server side so you wouldn't need to worry about it client side.

Comment: do you need the $ in $(title).text()?  I think if you are declaring it then all you would need would be title.text()

Comment: @adeneo Hey it works like a charm! So basically now the output looks like alert('')Some Text! . Thanks, may be you should enter it as an answer so I can approve it? One more thing though, since I want to set browser title with this text, I still get error because of the quotes inside alert, any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: Not sure why you would set the title to something containing script tags and an alert, but added an answer anyway. You can always just remove the script tags ?

Comment: @adeneo No the problem is that users input these titles (not me). Therefore, it could be just about anything.

Comment: Ah, okay, setting the document.title like below should work in most cases, and you can always use `string.replace("'","")` to get rid of the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.title = $('<div />').append( $('<div />').html( title ).text() ).text();
```

Appending the string twice should fix the htmlentities issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL as engine to store that kind of data, you are clearly using PHP scripting.  Suggestion: use PHP's strip_tag() and you are cutting "workload" for jQuery/Javascript by letting PHP do the work.

Comment: you mean while creating the json file I need to use that?

Comment: Okay i understand what you mean. But the thing is I am okay with users entering scripts or codes. I might even have to display codes in my page. I just want to get rid of scripts from this particular variable that I will use to set the page title.

Comment: If you allow people to post scripts to your site, your gunna have a bad time. imagine people doing a post `('html').html("");`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/305381/2033671

Comment: Allow the user input to be sent to server "as it is" (to .php file on your server).  On your server side, your php (the script that receives the POST, use strip_tag() to strip HTML out from the input before encoding it into htmlspecialchars, then you pass it to MySQL for inserting.

For example,
        <?php
        $input_ received = $_POST["nameOfYourInputFromForm"];
        $input_notags = strip_tag($input_ received);
        $final_input = htmlspecialchars( $input_notags, ENT_QUOTES);
        
        //$final_input then is ready for INSERT via MySQl
        ?>